# $M\xi$ forms a unital Hilbert algebra for some cyclic-separating vector $\xi$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra over a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and $\xi\in \mathcal H$ be a cyclic-separating vector for $M$, that is, $[M\xi]=[M'\xi]=\mathcal H$, where $M'$ is the commutant of $M$. Now consider the subset $\mathcal K$ of $\mathcal H$ defined by
$$\mathcal K :=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i \gamma_i: \eta_i,\gamma_i\in M\xi\right \},$$
that is, $\mathcal K$ is spanned linearly by all possible products $\eta\gamma$, $\eta,\gamma \in M \xi$. Let us define the product and involution on $M\xi$ by,
$$(x\xi)(y\xi)=xy\xi, ~~\text{and}~~ (x\xi)^*=x^*\xi, ~\forall x,y \in M$$
Consider the inner product in $M\xi$ inherited from $\mathcal H$. Now Wikipedia says that $M\xi$ forms a unital left Hilbert algebra. I am okay with other conditions but I am not able to solve the two things that:
$(1)$ $\mathcal K$ is dense in $M\xi$ with respect to the given inner product.
$(2)$ The map $\theta: M\xi \to M\xi$ by $\theta(x\xi)=x^*\xi$ is pre-closed.

One thing is that, $\mathcal K$ forms an ideal for $M\xi$ also $\xi$ is the identity of $M\xi$, but I am unable to figure out how to show the denseness. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your valuable time and effort. Thank you.

Comment: You don't say which Wikipedia article this is coming from, but as written you have that $\mathcal K=M\xi$, since $\xi=\xi\xi\in\mathcal K$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami here it is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomita%E2%80%93Takesaki_theory#Left_Hilbert_algebras

Comment: And where does the page say that $\mathfrak A$ is distinct from $M\xi$ as sets?

Comment: @MartinArgerami sir, in my case $\mathfrak A$ is same as $M\xi$, but By definition of left Hilbert algebra, I want to show $\mathfrak A^2$ is dense in $\mathfrak A$, in my case $\mathfrak A^2=\mathcal K$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami and by your first comment we have $\mathfrak A^2=\mathfrak A$, in this case. But I am unable to show the second one, that is, $\theta$ is pre-closed.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$, being a von Neumann algebra, is unital, you have that
$$
\mathcal K=\{x\xi:\ x\in M\}=M\xi. 
$$

A linear operator $T$  operator is pre-closed (*closable* is the usual modern term) if, among other [equivalent conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Extension-related), given a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in its domain such that $x_n\to 0$ and $Tx_n\to y$, then $y=0$. So we need to assume that $x_n\xi\to0$ and that $x_n^*\xi\to y\xi$. Now we need to use that $\xi$ is both cyclic and separating. Let $z\in M'$. Then
$$
\langle y\xi,z\xi\rangle=\lim_n\langle x_n^*\xi,z\xi\rangle
=\lim_n\langle \xi,x_nz\xi\rangle
=\lim_n\langle \xi,zx_n\xi\rangle
=\lim_n\langle z^*\xi,x_n\xi\rangle\to0.
$$
As $M'\xi$ is dense in $H$ (because $\xi$ is separating for $M$), this shows that $y\xi=0$ and hence $\theta$ is closable.